# Override .css stylesheet file (not inline)

Tags: javascript, html, css, liquid

Is it possible to somehow override the default (in this case liquid) CSS stylesheet, but without using inline styles?
Also I want that style to apply only to that specific page, and not any others.

Yes, I can use `!important` inside `<style>` tag on that specific page, but I would need to reset a lot of things. It just too much work, and looks very messy.

So is there any way I could reset ALL elements to default property values, and use my own style just on that one page?

Comment: You could just not use your main css file in that particular page if that's an option

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't modify your `.css` files, but you can replace files dynamically using `js`.

```
function replaceFile(newFile, fileLink) {
    var oldcss = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(fileLink);
    var newcss = document.createElement("link");
    newcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newcss.setAttribute("href", newFile);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newcss, oldcss);
}
```

Another solution, would be to add the desired styles using `jQuery` or `js`.

```
$('.demo').css({'background-color':'red','color':'white');
```

Comment: Your first solution is what I had in mind, but I'm not familiar how liquid compiles files when rendering, and in this specific case I'm not sure it will work. 
To access any stylesheet in liquid I'm doing this in " index.liquid "

`<link type="text/css" href="{{ 'styles.css' | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">`  
So I would need to render new stylesheet also, then replace the theme active one  with that new rendered link? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

css stands for Cascading Style Sheets so once you've added a style you can only change or remove it by using another style. to answer your question specifically ***no*** you can not. or as mentioned in the comments just remove the stylesheet from that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all elements inside a wrapper with * and override:

Example:

```css
.mylink{
  color: red;
}

.mylink:hover{
  color: black;
}

.reset *{
  color: orange;
}

.reset *:hover{
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
This is the link without reset: 
<a href="#" class="mylink">Link</a>


<div class="reset">
    This is the link with reset: 
    <a href="#" class="mylink">Link</a>
</div>
```